# why JSON return html

Tags: json, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.1. I try to get some data in JSON format through the controller, but it return html instead of json.

create.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'schedule']) !!}

@include('schedule.form',['submitButtonText'=>'Submit'])
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

edit.blade.php

```
   {!! Form::model($schedule,['method'=>'PATCH','url' => 'schedule/'. $schedule->scheduleID ]) !!}
    @include('schedule.form',['submitButtonText'=>'Update'])

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Ajax in schedule.form

```
 $.post('../schedule/loadRoute',{routeID:routeID},function(r){
        console.log(r);
        $.each(JSON.parse(r), function(key, value){ 

               coordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat,value.lon));
               if(value.is_station==1){
                   addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat,value.lon),value.name);
               }

        });

        clearMap();

    });
```

loadRoute function in controller

```
public function loadRoute(Request $request){

   $routeID=$request->get('routeID');



    $station=Station::where('route_id',$routeID)->get()->toArray();


    echo json_encode($station);

}
```

**Edit**

routes.php

```
 Route::group(
    ['middleware' => ['web']],
    function () {
        Route::auth();

        Route::get('schedule/getScheduleByRouteID/{routeID}', 'ScheduleController@getScheduleByRouteID');

        Route::resource('schedule', 'ScheduleController', ['except' => ['destroy', 'show']]);

            Route::post('schedule/loadRoute','ScheduleController@loadRoute');
});
```

Both create and edit page share the same schedule.form, but the JSON data is returned successfully in create page only, for edit page it return html instead of JSON, and I get this error in console (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0)

Both page using the same form, but why it doesn't work when comes to edit page?

Comment: Probably because the server is returning HTML due to some server error or it's actually supposed to do that and you're accessing it incorrectly

Comment: Is the `Ajax in schedule.form` section in a blade file or a javascript file?

Comment: it's in the blade file script section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine one of the reasons you're seeing this is because of your `loadRoute` route underneath the `resource` route.

Try changing the order to:

```
Route::get('schedule/getScheduleByRouteID/{routeID}', 'ScheduleController@getScheduleByRouteID');

Route::post('schedule/loadRoute','ScheduleController@loadRoute');

Route::resource('schedule', 'ScheduleController', ['except' => ['destroy', 'show']]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-supplementing-resource-controllers

Also, you should `return` from a controller not `echo`:

```
public function loadRoute(Request $request)
{
    return Station::where('route_id', $request->get('routeID'))->get();
}
```

In the above `Laravel` will automatically `json_encode()` the response and add the appropriate headers.

With your `$.post` call I would change it to the following:

```
$.post('{{ url('schedule/loadRoute') }}', {routeID: routeID, _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'}, function (r) {
    console.log(r);

    $.each(r, function (key, value) {

        coordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.lon));
        if (value.is_station == 1) {
            addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.lon), value.name);
        }

    });

    clearMap();

}, 'json');
```

This is because Laravel will now be returning a proper `json` response with the correct headers so you shouldn't need to `JSON.parse()` it. Also, you don't appear to be providing the `csrf_token` so that has been added to the data object as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, thanks! This solved my problem.  Forgot to mention, I added the header and token 
<meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
  
   headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
});

But it doesn't work in edit page, I don't actually know that it done by Laravel automatically, still new to it , thanks for help!